# Не отображается маркер в Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api

Карта отображается, а маркер - нет. В чем ошибка?

Функция находится в `<body>`:

```
<div id="map_canvas">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.885175, 27.454120);
            var settings = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                },
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
        }
        var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(53.885175, 27.454120);
        var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: companyPos,
            map: map,
            //title:"Merc",         
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Когда вызывается функция `initialize`? Это первый момент. Второй момент: переменная `map` объявлена внутри функции `initialize` - вне функции (в `map: map,`) она попросту не существует.

Comment: <body onload="initialize()">

Comment: 'function initialize() {
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.885175, 27.454120);
     var settings = {
     zoom: 16,
     center: latlng,
     mapTypeControl: true,
     mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
     navigationControl: true,
     navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
    }
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);'

Comment: И зачем же создавать новую карту вне функции? Почему бы просто не перенести `var companyPos = ... });` и т.д. внутрь функции?

Comment: @Regent тогда карта совсем не появляется! если занести маркер внутрь!

Comment: @Regent Заработало! СПасибо!

Comment: @Regent Пожалуйста, перенесите ваши рекомендации из комментариев в ответ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вопрос только в том, примет ли ответ автор. Отвечать на специфические (ценные только для самого автора) вопросы с репутацией автора `1` - тот ещё риск.

Comment: @Илья Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что переменная `map` не существует внутри кода:

```
var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: companyPos,
    map: map,
});
```

По той причине, что `map` - локальная переменная внутри функции `initialize`.

Имеет смысл смысл весь код размести внутри функции `initialize`:

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.885175, 27.454120);
    var settings = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
    var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(53.885175, 27.454120);
    var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: companyPos,
        map: map,       
    });
}
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7erwfzj/).